# Issue with inheriting from the django-graphene default GraphQLView

Tags: python, django

I have the need to do the following:

```
    path(
        '<uuid:uuid>/graphql',
        csrf_exempt(
            viewsets.MyCustomGraphQLView.as_view()
        )
    ),
```

That is, to pass in a `uuid` which can reference a different graphql schema dynamically.

I'm attempting to do something like the following:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from graphql.type.schema import GraphQLSchema
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView

class MyCustomGraphQLView(
    GraphQLView
):
    def __init__(
        self, *args, **kwargs
    ):
        super(MyCustomGraphQLView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.schema = self.get_object().get_schema()

        assert isinstance(
            self.schema, GraphQLSchema
        ), "A Schema is required to be provided to GraphQLView."

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return MyObject.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.uuid) // None

        print(MyObject.objects.get(uuid=self.uuid)) // None

        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, uuid=self.uuid)
        return obj
```

However, I'm not seeing that the uuid kwarg from `path()` is not being passed into the class ... that is, `self.kwargs` is None, and `self.uuid` is also None.

How can I get `MyCustomGraphQLView` to inherit the `setup()` from `from django.views.generic import View`?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to pass an uuid to the URL/View in the first place

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I’m creating a dynamic schema from a dataset - so each dataset will get their own GraphQL endpoint to interrogate the data. There kay be upwards of 10000 datasets so each one needs its own endpoint to query.

Comment: afaik, GraphQL doesn't work like that.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I think for this example, and coupled with dynamic schema per dataset - I need to do it this way. It's a graph for each specific dataset.